# The correct way to invoke an async function main?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-mysql2

I have some nodejs scripts - i.e. processes which do a job and complete, rather than run continuously.

I use async functions, for example:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
...

async function main() {
    var conn = await mysql.createConnection(config.mysql);
    ...
    var [response, error] = await conn.execute(`
        DELETE something
        FROM some_table
        WHERE field = ?
    `, [value]);
    ...
```

Is the following code:

```
main().then(() => process.exit(0)).catch(err => { console.error(err); process.exit(1); });
```

the best/correct way to start execution of the async code?

(It works, but I want to make sure that I'm not leaving any holes which might cause surprises, such as exceptions being silently swallowed.)

Why does `conn.execute()` **return** an `error` (which I need to manually check) rather than throwing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `then` together with `async..await` isn't necessary because it's syntactic sugar for `then`.

Entry point could be `async` IIFE (IIAFE):

```
(async () => {
  try {
    var conn = await mysql.createConnection(config.mysql);
    ...
    var [response] = await conn.execute(`
        SELECT something
        FROM some_table
        WHERE field = ?
    `, [value]);
    ...
    process.exit(0);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
})();
```

There also may be no need for `process.exit(0)` if the connection was closed.

> Why does conn.execute() return an error (which I need to manually check) rather than throwing one?

It doesn't, and isn't conventional for promise-enabled functions to return an error in a result.

Callback-based `execute` [uses error-first callback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-prepared-statements) for errors. Promise-based `execute` can't throw an error because it returns a promise which is rejected in case of error.

As [the documentation](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md#es7-async-await) shows, the second element is `fields` and not `error`:

```
const [rows, fields] = await conn.execute('select ?+? as sum', [2, 2]);
```

It may return rejected promise which can be caught with `try..catch` inside `async` function in case of error.

Comment: I had a cut/paste error, the query was mistakenly a SELECT.  It is now, correctly, a DELETE, which does not return `[rows, fields]`.

Comment: I'm unable to currently test what execute returns in case of DELETE but I'm positive it should reject an error, not resolve with it, so it can be caught with try..catch inside async. Why did you decide that it returns an error, *Why does conn.execute() return an error*?

Comment: I've just done some testing, and bad SQL causes an Error to be thrown, not returned.  With good SQL, the return value is the two-element array `[ResultSetHeader, undefined]`, which implies there could be something in the second position.  I will post another comment...

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've accepted your answer.  I can't find where I read that DELETEs and UPDATEs returned [ResultSetHeader, Error] - I may have just assumed it based on the callbacks from the non-async functions.  Still confused as to what might appear in the second position of the returned array.

Answer (score 2):

The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which returns an AsyncFunction object. An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, using an implicit Promise to return its result. But the syntax and structure of your code using async functions is much more like using standard synchronous functions.

You can also define async functions using an async function expression.

```
async function f() {

  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://no-such-url');
  } catch(err) {
    alert(err); // TypeError: failed to fetch
  }
}

f();
```

you can also immediately call an asynce function using the syntax below

```
(async () => {

})();
```

Comment: This gives me `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`.

Comment: Your first example still looks bad.  Are you using nodejs, or a browser?  Nodejs doesn't have `alert`.  If I replace `alert` and `fetch` with functions which exist, I just get the *promise* **returned**, but **not executed**.

Comment: Its about how to call async . Nothing node specific

Comment: you get the resolved value or reject value. Please look into promise more

Comment: Thanks for your help, but sorry, I don't see that in nodejs v10.15.3.  Are you using nodejs or a browser?  If you're using nodejs, where are `fetch` and `alert` coming from.

Comment: `f()` returns `Promise {
  undefined,
  domain:
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        removeListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        newListener: [Function: updateExceptionCapture],
        error: [Function: debugDomainError] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] } }`

Comment: Thats a pseudo code. Replace the insides of the function with your algorithm

Comment: you can use . f().then(res=>{ // handle res });

Comment: with `main().then(() => process.exit(0)).catch(err => { console.error(err); process.exit(1); });`